# Importing from CSV, objects unintentionally saving more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, hash, import, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to add an 'import via CSV' function to my app. I've been playing around with the code to figure out how it works. In my app a `User has_many :websites` and a `Website has_many :links`. This is what I have currently:

```
def create
  file = params[:file]
  @hash = {} 
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    hash = row.to_hash.slice("link", "project", "comment", "email")
    site = row["website"]
    @hash.has_key?(site) ? @hash[site] << hash : @hash.merge!(site => [hash])
    @hash.keys.each { |key| create_site(key, @hash[key]) }
  end
  flash[:success] = "File imported successfully! Links are currently being processed."
  redirect_to new_import_site_path
end

private

def create_site(site_link, links_array)
  website = current_user.websites.build(link: site_link)
  links_array.each do |link|
    website.links.build(page: link["link"], validation_id: current_user.id)
  end
  website.save
end
```

The code is generating the correct hash, e.g:

```
{"http://google.com"=>[{"link"=>"http://stackoverflow.com", "project"=>"Test", "comment"=>"this is a comment", "email"=>"email@gmail.com"}, {"link"=>"http://golf.com", "project"=>nil, "comment"=>"this is a comment", "email"=>"email@gmail.com"}], "http://yahoo.com"=>[{"link"=>"http://bing.com", "project"=>"Test", "comment"=>"this is a comment", "email"=>"email@gmail.com"}]}
```

If I run the code in my rails console using the hash above it creates only 2 websites and 3 links as expected, however in my app it creates 5 websites and 6 links:

```
Website             ID   Associated Link            ID
http://yahoo.com  | 406  http://bing.com          | 1223
http://google.com | 405  http://golf.com          | 1222
http://google.com | 405  http://stackoverflow.com | 1221
http://yahoo.com  | 404  http://bing.com          | 1220
http://google.com | 403  http://stackoverflow.com | 1219
http://google.com | 402  http://stackoverflow.com | 1218
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each row in your CSV file, you are re-creating all the sites seen in previous rows. I don't think that is your intent.

The answer is to move the culprit line of code out of the loop so that you create each site exactly once and only after you have finished the links arrays.

```
def create
  file = params[:file]
  @hash = {} 
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    hash = row.to_hash.slice("link", "project", "comment", "email")
    site = row["website"]
    @hash.has_key?(site) ? @hash[site] << hash : @hash.merge!(site => [hash])
  end

  # moved this out
  @hash.keys.each { |key| create_site(key, @hash[key]) }

  flash[:success] = "File imported successfully! Links are currently being processed."
  redirect_to new_import_site_path
end
```